# Painted shape keeps vibrating after stopping

Tags: java, swing, collision-detection

I tried to recreate some physics by creating a ball that bounces from the sides and that slows down. The ball stops moving in the x direction, but it keeps vibrating like only 1 pixel up and down in the y direction. Also it does this a little bit above the bottom border.

Also, is my code readable/good practise?

*Bouncy.java*

```
package Bouncy;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Bouncy {

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Bouncy Balls");
        Board board = new Board();
        frame.getContentPane().add(board);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setLocation(2000, 50);
        board.requestFocusInWindow();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }

}
```

*Board.java*

```
package Bouncy;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Board extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    public static final int BOARDWIDTH = 800;
    public static final int BOARDHEIGHT = 800;

    private Ball ball;

    public Board() {

        Dimension preferedDimension = new Dimension(BOARDWIDTH, BOARDHEIGHT);
        setPreferredSize(preferedDimension);
        ball = new Ball(15, 0);
        Timer animationTimer = new Timer(17, this);
        animationTimer.start();
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        ball.applyPhysics();
        repaint();
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        RenderingHints rh = new RenderingHints(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2d.setRenderingHints(rh);

        ball.display(g2d);

        g2d.dispose();
    }
}
```

*Ball.java*

```
package Bouncy;

import java.awt.*;

public class Ball {

    private int xPos;
    private int yPos;
    private double dx;
    private double dy;
    private int ballWidth;
    private int ballHeight;

    public Ball() {
        this(0, 0);
    }

    public Ball(int dx, int dy) {
        ballWidth = 50;
        ballHeight = ballWidth;
        xPos = 0;
        yPos = 0;
        this.dx = dx;
        this.dy = dy;
    }

    public void applyPhysics() {
        bounceX();
        applyXFriction();
        bounceY();
    }

    public void bounceX() {
        if (xPos > Board.BOARDWIDTH - ballWidth) {
            xPos = Board.BOARDWIDTH - ballWidth;
            dx = -dx;
        } else if (xPos < 0) {
            xPos = 0;
            dx = -dx;
        } else {
            xPos += dx;
        }
    }

    public void applyXFriction() {
        final double xFriction = .95;

        if (yPos == Board.BOARDHEIGHT - ballHeight) {
            dx *= xFriction;
            if (Math.abs(dx) < .5) {
                dx = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    public void bounceY() {
        final int gravity = 12;
        final double energyLoss = .75;
        final double dt = .2;

        if (yPos > Board.BOARDHEIGHT - ballHeight){
            yPos = Board.BOARDHEIGHT - ballHeight;
            dy = -dy * energyLoss;
        } else if (yPos < 0) {
            yPos = 0;
            dy *= -energyLoss;
        } else {
            dy += gravity * dt;
            yPos += dy * dt + .5 * gravity * dt * dt;
        }
    }

    public void display(Graphics2D g2d) {
        g2d.fillOval(xPos, yPos, ballWidth, ballHeight);
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Is the ball meant to stop bouncing at the end of the program?

Comment: @Alan The ball starts at the top left of the screen, gets a beginning velocity in the x direction, and gravity pulls it down in the y direction. After bouncing a few times, the ball is supposed to stop, but it keeps vibrating in the same spot after a few bounces.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inside your apply friction method, where you set dx to 0, also set dy to 0. This will stop the ball moving along both the X and Y axis

```
if (Math.abs(dx) < .5)
{
       dx = 0;
       dy = 0;
}
```

This will stop the ball vibrating:

```
if (Math.abs(dy * dt + .5 * gravity * dt * dt) < 1.5 && yPos == Board.BOARDHEIGHT - ballHeight) 
{
    dy = 0;
    yPos = Board.BOARDHEIGHT - ballHeight;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but adding dy=0; to that piece of code will stop the x and y directions simultaneously. So as long as the ball is still rolling along the bottom, the ball also keeps vibrating. I can't check for Math.abs(dy < .5) for example, since dy also gets that low when it is in the sky in it starts turning due to gravity. And do you know why it bounces a bit above the bottom instead of against the bottom?

Comment: When I checked it bounced against the bottom.

Comment: This is what it looks like on my screen: http://gyazo.com/7d1b007cbd7e32a355283f6ca1ba52fc
(it still vibrates when still, but the frame rate is too low to see it)

Comment: Inside bounceY() : if (yPos > Board.BOARDHEIGHT - (ballHeight-10))   That should make it move down further before it bounces. Alternativaly you could create a new constant instead of using ballHeight-10 and set it to 40

Comment: That also seems to make it stop moving along the X axis first, and then later stop bouncing

Comment: @Alan No unfortunately that doesn't work, however, setting frame.setResizable in Bouncy.java to true, or removing that line, seems to work... Do you know why? It ends on the bottom, but while bouncing at the beginning it sometimes goes through the bottom...

Comment: I would imagine it's going through the bottom of the screen because if it's 5 pixels away from the wall and yPos += dy * dt + .5 * gravity * dt * dt; gets called and the total is equal to 15, it will push it under the boundary. Then it gets caught by yPos = Board.BOARDHEIGHT - ballHeight; and it's placed back on the boundary and sent back in the opposite direction

Comment: @Alan setResizable to true made the bottom work.
if (Math.abs(dy * dt + .5 * gravity * dt * dt) < 2 && yPos == Board.BOARDHEIGHT - ballHeight) { 
            dy = 0;
            yPos = Board.BOARDHEIGHT - ballHeight;
}
This code made the ball stop vibrating, but the 2 has to become large when energyLoss becomes larger, and I don't understand there relationship